# How to handle data set without unique ID

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a data import routine from one source into another and I've got one table that doesn't have it's own unique identifier.  Instead it uses a combination of four fields to determine the record to be modified.  My source table structure is below:

feed_hcp_leasenote table:

```
BLDGID varchar(255),
LEASID varchar(255),
NOTEDATE varchar(255),
REF1 varchar(255),
NOTETEXT varchar(8000),
tempid int PRIMARY, AUTONUMBER
```

The first four are the fields which, when evaluated altogether, make a record unique in the source database.  I'm importing this data into two tables, one for the note and another for the other fields.  Here is my structure for the new database:

lease_note table:

```
lnid int PRIMARY AUTONUMBER,
notetext longtext,
lid int (lease ID, links to lease table)
```

customfield_data table (holds other data):

```
cfdid int PRIMARY AUTONUMBER,
data_date dateteime,
data_smtext varchar(1000),
linkid int (links the data to its source ID)
cfid int (links the data to its field type)
```

The problem that I'm running into is when I try to identify those records that exist in the source database without a match in the new database my query seems to be duplicating records to the point that the query never finishes and locks up my server.  I can successfully query based on BLDGID and LEASID and limit the query to the proper records but when I try to JOIN the customfield_data table aliased to the NOTEDATE and REF1 fields it starts to exponentially duplicate records.  Here's my query:

```
SELECT NOTEDATE, REF1, REF2, LASTDATE, USERID, NOTETEXT, lid
FROM feed_hcp_leasenote
JOIN customfield_data mrileaseid ON feed_hcp_leasenote.LEASID = mrileaseid.data_smtext AND mrileaseid.cfid = 36
JOIN leases ON mrileaseid.linkid = leases.lid
JOIN suites ON leases.sid = suites.sid
JOIN floors ON suites.fid = floors.fid
JOIN customfield_data coid ON floors.bid = coid.linkid AND coid.cfid = 1 AND coid.data_smtext = feed_hcp_leasenote.BLDGID
JOIN customfield_data status ON leases.lid = status.linkid AND status.cfid = 27 AND status.data_smtext <> 'I'
WHERE tempid NOT IN (
  SELECT tempid
  FROM feed_hcp_leasenote
  JOIN customfield_data mrileaseid ON feed_hcp_leasenote.LEASID = mrileaseid.data_smtext AND mrileaseid.cfid = 36
  JOIN leases ON mrileaseid.linkid = temp_leases.lid
  JOIN suites ON leases.sid = suites.sid
  JOIN floors ON suites.fid = floors.fid
  JOIN customfield_data coid ON floors.bid = coid.linkid AND coid.data_smtext = feed_hcp_leasenote.BLDGID AND coid.cfid = 1
  JOIN customfield_data notedate ON STR_TO_DATE(feed_hcp_leasenote.NOTEDATE, '%e-%b-%Y') = notedate.data_date AND notedate.cfid = 55 
  JOIN customfield_data ref1 ON feed_hcp_leasenote.REF1 = ref1.data_smtext AND ref1.cfid = 56
  JOIN lease_notes ON leases.lid = lease_notes.lid AND notedate.linkid = lease_notes.lnid AND ref1.linkid = lease_notes.lnid )
```

At the moment, I've narrowed the problem down to the NOT IN subquery -- running just that part crashes the server.  I imagine the problem is that because there can be multiple notes with the same BLDGID, LEASID, NOTEDATE, and REF1 (but not all 4), the query keeps selecting back on itself and effectively creating an infinite loop.

Short of modifying the source database to include a unique ID (which I can't do) does anyone see a solution to this?  Thanks in advance!

**(Edits based on feedback)**

Sorry for the lack of information, I was worried about that.  Basically I'm importing the data in feed_hcp_leasenote from a CSV file dumped from another database that I have no control over.  I add a tempid field once the data is imported into my server with the idea of using it in the SELECT WHERE tempid NOT IN query, though I'm not married to that approach.

My goal is to split the data in feed_hcp_leasenote into two tables: lease_note which holds the primary record (with a unique ID) and the note itself and; customfield_data which holds other data related to the record.

The source data feed consists of about 65,000 records, of which I'm importing about 25,000 since the remainder are connected to records that have been deactivated.

**(2nd Edit)**

Visual Schema of relevant tables: http://www.tentenstudios.com/clients/relynx/schema.png

EXPLAIN query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     status  ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     cfid    4   const   928     Using where
1   PRIMARY     mrileaseid  ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     linkid  5   rl_hpsi.status.linkid   19  Using where
1   PRIMARY     leases  eq_ref  PRIMARY,sid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.mrileaseid.linkid   1   Using where
1   PRIMARY     suites  eq_ref  PRIMARY,fid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.leases.sid  1    
1   PRIMARY     floors  eq_ref  PRIMARY,bid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.suites.fid  1    
1   PRIMARY     feed_hcp_leasenote  ref     BLDGID,LEASID   LEASID  768     rl_hpsi.mrileaseid.data_smtext  19  Using where
1   PRIMARY     coid    ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     data_smtext     1002    rl_hpsi.feed_hcp_leasenote.BLDGID   10  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  feed_hcp_leasenote  eq_ref  PRIMARY,BLDGID,LEASID   PRIMARY     4   func    1    
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mrileaseid  ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     data_smtext     1002    rl_hpsi.feed_hcp_leasenote.LEASID   10  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  leases  eq_ref  PRIMARY,sid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.mrileaseid.linkid   1    
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  suites  eq_ref  PRIMARY,fid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.leases.sid  1    
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  floors  eq_ref  PRIMARY,bid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.suites.fid  1    
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ref1    ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     data_smtext     1002    rl_hpsi.feed_hcp_leasenote.REF1     10  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  lease_notes     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.ref1.linkid     1   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  coid    ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     data_smtext     1002    rl_hpsi.feed_hcp_leasenote.BLDGID   10  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  notedate    ref     linkid,cfid     linkid  5   rl_hpsi.ref1.linkid     19  Using where
```

Comment: You clearly understand your schema and the relationship of your source and destination however there just isn’t enough information here for someone else to understand.  The notes table you refer to isn’t used in the query’s and where have all these temp tables come from?  Can you maybe at the very least proved an output of explain?

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that I haven't provided enough information and I just realized that I used my temp query -- I'm still operating on temp tables which are cloned from the live tables for this testing phase.  I'll update my initial question to match.

Comment: @Sean: "I'm still operating on temp tables which are cloned from the live tables" do you REALLY mean temp tables (lost at end of session) or do youmean temporary tables? I thought you couldn't make any schema changes?

Comment: No, don't worry about the temp_xxx tables -- I cloned my live data tables into temp_xxx to operate on.  These are not true temp tables.  I can make schema changes to my own database but not to the source from which I'm importing.

Comment: @SeanCunningham can you please provide the schema one you've imported teh CSV data AND the final schema you want to merge it into - a few rows of example data in each will help - it would also help if you ran your SELECT query with the word EXPLAIN in front of it and pasted the output - i'm guessing however it will be easier to help you find another query than 'fix' yours.

Comment: I agree on the query, this one may be a lost cause but I'll add the EXPLAIN to my original question anyway.  Are you looking for a graphical schema?  I'll post that but if you're looking for something other than the table structure I'm not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't have it's own unique identifier. Instead it uses a combination of four fields to determine the record to be modified

No: if the four fields in combination constitute a unique key, then you have a unique identifier - just one with four parts.

> BLDGID varchar(255),
>   LEASID varchar(255),
>   NOTEDATE varchar(255),
>   REF1 varchar(255),
>   NOTETEXT varchar(8000)

So you've no idea how the data is actually structured or you go this from a MSAccess programmer who doesn't know either.

> SELECT NOTEDATE, REF1, REF2, LASTDATE, USERID, NOTETEXT, lid
>   FROM feed_hcp_leasenote

OMG. If that's the answer then you're asking the wrong questions.

> Short of modifying the source database to include a unique ID (which I can't do) does anyone see a solution to this?

Find another job? Seriously. If you can't add a primary key to the import table / can't import it into a temporary table with a primary key defined, then you will spend a stupid amount of time trying to fix this.

BTW: While innodb will handle keys up to 3072 bytes (1024 on 32-bit) this will continue to run like a dog until you reduce your column sizes or use a hash of the actually PK data as the primary key.

It's not clear from your question how many rows you are adding / how many rows are already in the database. Nor have you provided the structure of the other tables.  **Nor have you provided an explain plan** which should be your starting point for any performance problems.

It might be possible to get this running a lot faster - it's impossible to say from the information you have provided. But given the **ridiculous** constraint that you have to make it faster without changing the schema, I wonder what other horrors await.

I did think that, without knowing the details of the current schema, it would be possible to breakdown the current query into several components and check each one, maintaining a score in the import table - then use the score to determine what had unmatched data - however this requires schema changes too.

BTW have a google for the DISTINCT keyword in SQL.

Comment: "So you've no idea how the data is actually structured or you go this from a MSAccess programmer who doesn't know either." Not sure what you mean here.  This is the data structure that I'm getting from the source.  "OMG. If that's the answer then you're asking the wrong questions." I may very well be asking the wrong question, but I don't believe that part of the query is an answer at all.  Again, not sure what you're getting at here.  "Nor have you provided an explain plan" I thought that was an Oracle-specific feature?

Comment: "If you can't add a primary key to the import table / can't import it into a temporary table with a primary key defined, then you will spend a stupid amount of time trying to fix this."  I'm afraid you might be right about that one.  My other option is to delete *all* notes that pertain to a LEASID (which I can do) and then add them back in during every import as opposed to simply updating the records.  This doesn't seem like a great solution either.

Comment: @Sean: No EXPLAIN is available on every relational DBMS I've ever used - including MySQL. "...I'm getting from the source" - what source? It smells like very bad data modelling.

Comment: The source in this case is the data contained in feed_hcp_leasenote.  I've dumped a CSV file which I exported from the source database (that I can't modify) into my database which I can modify.